# Windows Server 2008 R2 network performance degrade over time

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

We've got **Windows Server 2008 R2** which servers as **DC**, **Exchange** mail server and **file share** (Let's call in **Server-1**). We also have fiber channel network storage, connected to this server. Putting there backups with Symantec Backup Exec 2010 (hosed on different server) over network regularly (it will be **Server-SBE**).

The problem is that over time (couple weeks usually) it's network receive speed on **Server-1** goes down. It remains 1 Gbps in network adapter info but practically I see 300-400 kbps when I try to copy file to this server from some other servers, including Server-SBE.

It's not network storage problem, since copying to local disk C slow as well. It is not disk subsystem problem either, since copying files locally goes OK.

And it's also kinda selective: for example I can copy file from my workstation to this server with healthy speed of 10 MB/s (since there is 100M connection between), but I cannot do the same from my SBE server (2008R2 as well) despite 1G connection between them. After reboot of Server-1 everything gets back to normal. But it's really bad, since backups are not finished over weekend.

Any thoughts how do deal with it or what could the reason?

Other info:

- Network Switch is Cisco C3560X
- RAID1 on both servers (HP DL360p Gen8) and Network Storage (DELL MD3600f)
- Server-1 is bare-metal, while Server-SBE housed on VMWare ESXi 5.1 (but we had same problems while it was bare-metal as well).

Comment: update NIC drivers, check TCP offload options. At the end of your post you suddenly introduce server2 but don't describe it so I'm at lost as to what the relation of server2 and server1 is.

Comment: Server-2 is Server-SBE. I wrote Server-2 first time but changed it to Server-SBE after text was ready to post to make less confusion but forgot to change last entry.

Comment: This is off-topic and I don't want to sound like a wiseguy, but in case you did not know that, I'd liek to tell you: Installing Exchange Server on a domain controller is not supported by Microsoft.

Comment: I know that and it was not my call either. I have to maintain configuration which was made long before me. Still, I doubt it's Exchange issue - too selective. I could be related though, since SBE backups Exchange among other systems.